# Multiple Custom Kendo Editor

Tags: jquery, html, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I am using kendoGid to show the data and it has (userName, firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber, roleName, supplierCode) fields. I am getting data accurately, all the CRUD operations are getting performed nicely.

Here is my grid code:

```
       var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: usersDataSource,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id:"$id",
                fields: {
                    userName: { },
                    firstName: {  },
                    lastName: { },
                    email: { },
                    phoneNumber: { },
                    roleName: { },
                    supplierCode: { }
                }
            }
        },
        editable: "popup",
        edit: function (e) {
            $(e.container).find('input[name="prontoCode"]').attr({ "hidden": true });

        },
        columns:
               [     .....Other Fields Definition ... 
                     {
                         field: "roleName",
                         title: "Role Name",
                         editor: rolesDropDownEditor
                     },
                     {
                         field: "prontoCode",
                         title: "Supplier Code",
                         editor: supplierDropDownEditor,
                     }
               ],
    });
```

As you can see above in my column definition, I used custom editor (kendoDropDown) and kendo popup editing property. 
Here is code for rolesDropDownEditor:

```
      function rolesDropDownEditor(container, options) {
        $('<input required name="' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDropDownList({
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "URL",
                            type: "get",
                            datatype: "json",
                        }
                    }
                },
                change: function (e) {
                    if (e.val == "Supplier") {
                   $(e.container).find('input[name="prontoCode"]').attr({ "hidden": false });
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

The values in rolesDropDown are (admin, Inspector, Engineer & Supplier), I want to show the supplierDropDown  when user select "Supplier" from the roleDropDown..
Any help on how can I show or hide one dropdown by another's change function? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the supplierDropDownEditor,
Find the TR(row) Selected.

```
    var tr = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(container[0]).closest("tr"))
```

Find the tr.roleName value.

According to the roleName create different dataSources(Just put the if-else block and add different ajax calls), Bind the required datasource.

please let me know if you need further clarification.